# redmine load_default_data failure

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, redmine

im having trouble setting up the default data environment in redmine + mysql. this is the error im getting. i think i have correctly set up the database and user so that this step should work. all priveleges are granted on the redmine user.  any ideas?

the installation step

*****@*****:~/Applications/redmine-1.0$ RAILS_ENV=production rake redmine:load_default_data
(in /home/*****/Applications/redmine-1.0)

Select language: bg, bs, ca, cs, da, de, el, en, en-GB, es, eu, fi, fr, gl, he, hr, hu, id, it, ja, ko, lt, lv, mn, nl, no, pl, pt, pt-BR, ro, ru, sk, sl, sr, sr-CY, sv, th, tr, uk, vi, zh, zh-TW [en]

Error: Mysql::Error: Table 'redmine.roles' doesn't exist: SELECT * FROM `roles` WHERE (`roles`.`builtin` = 0)  LIMIT 1
Default configuration data was not loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

missed an install step

RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate